# Descargar archivo de texto en browser

Tags: java, jsp, descarga

Quiero descargar un archivo .txt a traves de mi navegador, lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora es que el archivo se guarde en un ruta especifica, pero quisiera que se me descargar a traves del navegador para que se mas comodo para el usuario, aqui el codigo que tengo hasta ahora :

```
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
FileWriter fw = null;

$_Query="SELECT FROM PIEZAS";
rs1 = Gdr.consultar($_Query, 2);
String path = "C:/Users/Public/Downloads/";
java.util.Calendar fecha = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
String fechafile=fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.DATE) + ""+ fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH)    + "" + fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
String fileName = "ArunicoERP_"+fechafile+".txt";
fw = new FileWriter(path + fileName);

if (qr == 1) {
    rs1 = Gdr.consultar($_Query, 2);
    String path = "C:/Users/Public/Downloads/";
    java.util.Calendar fecha = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    String fechafile=fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.DATE) + ""+ fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH)    + "" + fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
    //String fileName = "ArunicoERP_"+fechafile+".txt";
    String fileName = "ArunicoERP_.txt";
    fw = new FileWriter(path + fileName);
    while (rs1.next()) {
        line.append(rs1.getString("cuenta").toString());

        if ((rs1.getString("tipo_entrega").toString().equals("ER"))) {
            String Plaza = rs1.getString("plaza").toString();
            if (!Plaza.equals("N")) {
                line.insert(0, "3");
                line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
                line.append(rs1.getString("plazan").toString());
                line.append(endLine);
            } else {
                String test = rs1.getString("fecha").toString();
                line.append(test);
                line.append("000000");
                if (rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("TI") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("CO") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("HI") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("PA") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("HE") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("OT")) {
                    line.insert(0, "1");
                    line.append("001");
                } else if (rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("VI") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("AS") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("SE") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("AB") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("CU") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("PR") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("SU") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("TO")) {
                    line.insert(0, "1");
                    line.append("002");
                }
                //line.append(dbAppHelper.fieldValue("tipo_entrega_cat").toString());
                line.append(rs1.getString("visita").toString());
                line.append(rs1.getString("parentezco").toString());
                line.append(rs1.getString("nombre").toString().replace(".", " ").replace(",", " ").replace("{", " ").replace("}", " ").replace("/", " ").replace("*", " ").replace("-", " ").replace("_", " ").replace("+", " "));
                line.append(rs1.getString("identificacion").toString());
                line.append(rs1.getString("nidentificacion").toString());
                line.append(endLine);
            }
        } else if ((rs1.getString("tipo_entrega").toString().equals("DR")) || rs1.getString("tipo_entrega").toString().equals("DI")) {
            if ((rs1.getString("motivo_qp").toString().equals("21"))) {
                line.insert(0, "2");
                line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
                line.append("000000");
                line.append(rs1.getString("visita").toString());
                line.append("08");
                line.append(endLine);
            } else if ((rs1.getString("motivo_qp").toString().equals("22"))) {
                line.insert(0, "8");
                line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
                line.append(endLine);
            }
            else if (rs1.getString("motivo").equals("06")){ //nueva condicion
                line.insert(0,"8");
                line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
                line.append(endLine);
            }
            else {
                line.insert(0, "2");
                line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
                line.append("000000");
                line.append(rs1.getString("visita").toString());
                line.append(rs1.getString("motivo").toString());
                line.append(endLine);
            }
        } else if ((rs1.getString("tipo_entrega").toString().equals("EC"))) {
            line.insert(0, "1");
            line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
            line.append("000000003PV                                       ");
            line.append(endLine);
        }

        fw.append(line.toString());
        line.setLength(0);
        if (r == 0) {%>
            <tr bgcolor='white' ALIGN='CENTER'>
        <%
            r = 1;
        } else {
            r = 0;
        %>
            <tr bgcolor='#E6E6E6' ALIGN='CENTER'>
    <%  } %>
            </tr>
    <%
    }
    fw.close();
    Gdr.cerrar();
    out.print("Archivo se ha procesado");
}
```

Comment: Tu explicación es ambigua

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con el siguiente código

```
FileInputStream archivo = new FileInputStream(path + fileName); 
int longitud = archivo.available();
byte[] datos = new byte[longitud];
archivo.read(datos);
archivo.close();

response. SetContentType("application/download"); 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+nFile);    

response.getOutputStream().write(datos);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
```

:

Comment: y en datos que iria ?

Comment: iria tu archivo FileInputStream

Comment: Lo pongo asi >> ouputStream.write(fw);  pero me marca un error : no suitable method found for write(java.io.FileWriter)

Comment: lo acabo de editar

Comment: Ahora me marca >> java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: cambia las ultimas lineas: `response.getOutputStream().write(datos);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();` lo edite

Comment: Mismo error java.lang.IllegalStateException :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48680/discussion-between-j-castro-and-jairo-ordaz-moreno).

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que el servlet no es más que un programa que *construye* la salida del servidor HTTP. Así, puedes indicar que se trata de una descarga y construir el archivo al vuelo (sin tocar el disco) en el stream de salida del servlet, algo como esto:

```
         StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

             $_Query="SELECT FROM PIEZAS";
             rs1 = Gdr.consultar($_Query, 2);
                    java.util.Calendar fecha = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
                    String fechafile=fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.DATE) + ""+ fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH)    + "" + fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
                    String fileName = "ArunicoERP_"+fechafile+".txt";

                    if (qr == 1) {
                    rs1 = Gdr.consultar($_Query, 2);
                    String path = "C:/Users/Public/Downloads/";
                    java.util.Calendar fecha = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
                    String fechafile=fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.DATE) + ""+ fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH)    + "" + fecha.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
                    //String fileName = "ArunicoERP_"+fechafile+".txt";
                    String fileName = "ArunicoERP_.txt";
                    //header, no puede haberse escrito nada en la salida antes de esto.
                    HttpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                    //puedes poner otro mime-type si es lo que conviene
                    response.setContentType("text/plain");
                    //obtenemos el stream de salida.
                    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();


                    while (rs1.next()) {

                    line.append(rs1.getString("cuenta").toString());

                    if ((rs1.getString("tipo_entrega").toString().equals("ER"))) {
                        String Plaza = rs1.getString("plaza").toString();
                        if (!Plaza.equals("N")) {
                            line.insert(0, "3");
                            line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
                            line.append(rs1.getString("plazan").toString());
                            line.append(endLine);
                        } else {
                            String test = rs1.getString("fecha").toString();
                            line.append(test);
                            line.append("000000");
                            if (rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("TI") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("CO") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("HI") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("PA") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("HE") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("OT")) {
                                line.insert(0, "1");
                                line.append("001");
                            } else if (rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("VI") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("AS") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("SE") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("AB") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("CU") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("PR") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("SU") || rs1.getString("parentezco").toString().equals("TO")) {
                                line.insert(0, "1");
                                line.append("002");
                            }
                            //line.append(dbAppHelper.fieldValue("tipo_entrega_cat").toString());
                            line.append(rs1.getString("visita").toString());
                            line.append(rs1.getString("parentezco").toString());
                            line.append(rs1.getString("nombre").toString().replace(".", " ").replace(",", " ").replace("{", " ").replace("}", " ").replace("/", " ").replace("*", " ").replace("-", " ").replace("_", " ").replace("+", " "));
                            line.append(rs1.getString("identificacion").toString());
                            line.append(rs1.getString("nidentificacion").toString());
                            line.append(endLine);
                        }
                    } else if ((rs1.getString("tipo_entrega").toString().equals("DR")) || rs1.getString("tipo_entrega").toString().equals("DI")) {
                        if ((rs1.getString("motivo_qp").toString().equals("21"))) {
                            line.insert(0, "2");
                            line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
                            line.append("000000");
                            line.append(rs1.getString("visita").toString());
                            line.append("08");
                            line.append(endLine);
                        } else if ((rs1.getString("motivo_qp").toString().equals("22"))) {
                            line.insert(0, "8");
                            line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
                            line.append(endLine);
                        } 
                        else if (rs1.getString("motivo").equals("06")){ //nueva condicion
                            line.insert(0,"8");
                            line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
                            line.append(endLine);
                        }
                        else {
                            line.insert(0, "2");
                            line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
                            line.append("000000");
                            line.append(rs1.getString("visita").toString());
                            line.append(rs1.getString("motivo").toString());
                            line.append(endLine);
                        }
                    } else if ((rs1.getString("tipo_entrega").toString().equals("EC"))) {
                        line.insert(0, "1");
                        line.append(rs1.getString("fecha").toString());
                        line.append("000000003PV                                       ");
                        line.append(endLine);
                    }

                    outStream.print(line.toString());
                    line.setLength(0);

                     Gdr.cerrar();
               }
               ouputStream.flush();
               ouputStream.close();
```

Comment: No me permite añadir este segmento de codigo>> HttpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName); me marca error

Comment: Ya veo, cámbia HttpServletResponse por solo response.

Comment: Ya lo cambie pero cuando lo ejecuto inmediatamente me regresa null

Comment: @Jairo, el código lo escribí aquí mismo en el browser, no tengo ahora las herramientas a mano, es de esperar que hagas el esfuerzo mínimo por entender la idea y antes de reportar un error te esfuerces por resolverlo tu mismo utilizando el depurador y todas las herramientas que están a tu disposición.

Comment: Si al final de cuentas no se resuelve, pero vienes con más información y alguna idea de por qué falla, seguro podemos llegar a una solución.

Answer (score 1):

Es más fácil con un Servlet, como se muestra a continuación:

```
@WebServlet("/DownloadFile")
public class DownloadFile extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int BYTES_DOWNLOAD = 1024;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                             "attachment;filename=downloadname.txt");
            ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
            InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/testing.txt");

            int read=0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

            while((read = is.read(bytes))!= -1){
                os.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            os.flush();
            os.close();
    }
}
```

Y el archivo lo pones en la carpeta **WebContent**:

[image: Localización del archivo]